# Running multiple SQL Queries are displaying in the wrong order

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run these SQL Queries:

```
$sql2="SELECT * from client where parent_client_id = '".$result["customerid"]."' ";
$rs2=mysql_query($sql2,$pbx01_conn) or die(mysql_error());
while($result2=mysql_fetch_array($rs2)) {
            $sql3="SELECT * from extension where client_id = '".$result2["id"]."' and type = 'term' ";
            $rs3=mysql_query($sql3,$pbx01_conn) or die(mysql_error());
            if(mysql_num_rows($rs3) > 0) {
                $result3=mysql_fetch_array($rs3);
                echo '<tr class="notfirst" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="document.location=\'sip:'.$result["customerid"].'*'.$result3["number"].'\'">
                <td>'.$result2["name"].'</td>
                <td>'.$result["customerid"].'*'.$result3["number"].'</td>
                <td>Phone Terminal</td>
                </tr>';
            }
            $sql3="SELECT * from extension where client_id = '".$result2["id"]."' and type = 'queue' ";
            $rs3=mysql_query($sql3,$pbx01_conn) or die(mysql_error());
            if(mysql_num_rows($rs3) > 0) {
                $result3=mysql_fetch_array($rs3);
                echo '<tr class="notfirst" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="document.location=\'sip:'.$result["customerid"].'*'.$result3["number"].'\'">
                <td>'.$result2["name"].'</td>
                <td>'.$result["customerid"].'*'.$result3["number"].'</td>
                <td>Queue</td>
                </tr>';
            }
```

So if on the first $sql3 there are 4 rows returned, it should be:

```
Phone Terminal
Phone Terminal
Phone Terminal
Phone Terminal
```

and on the second $sql3 there is 1 one returned it should be:

```
Queue
```

but its showing like

```
Phone Terminal
Phone Terminal
Phone Terminal
Queue
Phone Terminal
```

What have i done wrong?

Comment: how many rows are returing by $sql2 ?

Comment: $result3=mysql_fetch_array($rs3); where is the loop???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by creating a variable per query inside the while loop

then outside the while loop, i done:

```
    echo $term;
    echo $queue;
    echo $ivr;
    echo $voicecentre;
    echo $conference;
    echo $callback;
    echo $intercom;
    echo $queuecentre;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check when you concatenate a string, instead of echoing, that you have the same problem.

```
<?php
$sql2 = "SELECT * from client where parent_client_id = '".$result["customerid"]."' ";
$rs2 = mysql_query($sql2,$pbx01_conn) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = '';
while ($result2 = mysql_fetch_array($rs2)) {
    $sql3 = "SELECT * from extension where client_id = '".$result2["id"]."' and type = 'term' ";
    $rs3 = mysql_query($sql3,$pbx01_conn) or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($rs3) > 0) {
        $result3 = mysql_fetch_array($rs3);
        $rows .= '<tr class="notfirst" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="document.location=\'sip:'.$result["customerid"].'*'.$result3["number"].'\'">
        <td>'.$result2["name"].'</td>
        <td>'.$result["customerid"].'*'.$result3["number"].'</td>
        <td>Phone Terminal</td>
        </tr>';
    }
    $sql3 = "SELECT * from extension where client_id = '".$result2["id"]."' and type = 'queue' ";
    $rs3 = mysql_query($sql3,$pbx01_conn) or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($rs3) > 0) {
        $result3 = mysql_fetch_array($rs3);
        $rows .= '<tr class="notfirst" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="document.location=\'sip:'.$result["customerid"].'*'.$result3["number"].'\'">
        <td>'.$result2["name"].'</td>
        <td>'.$result["customerid"].'*'.$result3["number"].'</td>
        <td>Queue</td>
        </tr>';
    }
}
echo $rows;
?>
```

Comment: this just displays the same thing

Answer (score 0):

You are doing multiple things wrong:

1. you should not do sql queries within a loop. This is because you can in your case use both JOINs and UNION to get your results. The performance will be better as well.
2. The mysql extension you are using is as of PHP5.5 deprecated. You should use something else instead, such as PDO for example.
3. the code you show displays exactly what you see, obviously, and is correct in doing so.
   This is because you do this:

   if(mysql_num_rows($rs3) > 0) {

and then for the second query do this again:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($rs3) > 0) {
```

The code runs through both if statements as both are true, thus showing what you see. You most likely have both extension 'term' and 'queue' for the same client.
If you do not want to show both for the same client, use if else or a continue;

Comment: ok, i just realised its running all the queries inside the loop so will not display them in the correct order. whats the best way around it?

Comment: make single query with JOIN between client and extension tables and a WHERE clause for extension term or queue. Then loop in PHP over the results and echo only what you need in the proper order.